# Firebase error connecting SHA1 production fingerprint

Tags: android, firebase

We have encountered a Firebase error connecting SHA1 production fingerprint.

The app X was published in Google Play Store, but not connected to Firebase.
We have update the app using the old signing certificate (jks) and we have connect the application with a brand new firebase account.

We successfully add the Android app to the new project, but when we have tried to add the SHA1 fingerprint for production Firebase return us this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "clientauthconfig.clients.get not allowed: \ncom.google.identity.boq.appidentity.authorization.PermissionDeniedException",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.internal.firebase.v1.ErrorCode"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some ideas?

Answer (score 5):

**Did you enable the Google Play App Signing by any chance?**

If yes - you need to use the SHA-1 they generated for you, and not the one from the original keystore.

Go to your app in the `Google Play Console` --> `Release management` --> Use the `App signing certificate` SHA-1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, although you don't have to remove the already existing SHA-1 certificate, you can just add the new one.

Answer (score 1):

The SHA 1 fingerprint certificate was already **used by another account that we did not have access**. 
After we found this, and **we removed the certificate reference from this old account**, the new account has accept the fingerprint cert.

Comment: This will happen as well if you have different android flavors with the same app signing certificate. Manually adding the fingerprints to Firebase should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

These answers are correct, you should add the SHA-1 presented on Google Play Console, but there's one more step missing.

After you add the SHA-1 to your FireBase Project settings you need to download the updated google-services.json add it to your project and upload a new version to Google Play.